# What will be the Regular Expression for Numeric Value(with or without decimal) in actionscript3

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I want to validate a numeric value(with or without decimal point).
If I use

```
textInput.restrict = "0-9.";
```

it will only restrict to enter a number with 0-9 or '.'(decimal point).
But it doesn't restrict to enter double decimal(e.g-123.3.3)which is not a valid number.

So,what should be the regex for such scenario ?
Thank you!

Comment: And BMT formatting also required(B-billion,M-million,T-thousand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define the regular expression in ActionScript 3.0:

```
var decimalPattern:RegExp = /^\d+(\.\d+)?$/;
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
var decimalPattern:RegExp = new RegExp("^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$");
```

This pattern says "some digits, possibly followed by a '.' and more digits".

If you want a more generic solution, with consideration for things like negative numbers and commas (e.g. `-13,386.91`), then you could use: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/validators/NumberValidator.html

Comment: can you describe the tokens in regex in brief.

Comment: `\d` means "a digit" (0-9). `+` means "one or more of the previous expression". `\.` means "a literal '.' character". `?` means "zero or one of the previous expression". `^` and `$` are anchors to mark the start and end of a line, respectively. If you wish to learn about regular expressions more thoroughly, then google is your friend :)